# Finding $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{|xy|}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

How does one find the limit of

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{|xy|}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$$?

Can someone justify the steps they make? The answers in my book involves using some smart inequality that I've never seen before and could only say it resembles the AM-GM inequality

Comment: Is the denominator $s^2$ or $x^2$? Also, try converting to polar coordinates; not sure if it will work, but it may.

Comment: It is $x^2$ sorry and yes! Polar coordinates seem to does the trick! Thanks

Comment: I will post an answer below as well for completeness.

Comment: Yeah thanks and I'll accept it afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transforming to polar coordinates, $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$, gives the limit
$$\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow0^+}\frac{r^2|\sin(2\theta)|}{2r},$$
which is easily evaluated to be $0$.

Comment: Does it really matter if $r \to 0^+$ or $-$?

Comment: No. However mathematically, since $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\geq 0$, technically $\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow0}f(r)$ doesn't exist as $r$ is not defined for negative numbers. Hence, I included explicitly that it is for positive $r\rightarrow0$.

Comment: I thought by convention $r$ can be negative because $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$

Comment: $r$ can never be negative. $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ by definition, and hence by definition of $\sqrt{(\cdot)}$, it must be positive. $r^2 = x^2+y^2$ by consequence of the definition of $r$.

Comment: There are two conventions for graphing polar curves. They go as follows. (i) $r=-2$, $\theta=\pi/3$ is not allowed or (ii) the point $r=-2$, $\theta=\pi/3$ is the point obtained thus: graph $r=2$, $\theta=\pi/3$ as usual, then **reflect** the result in the origin, or equivalently rotate by a half-turn. So in a homework problem, one has to be aware of which convention is the one used in the course. In our case, we can choose either convention, and $r\ge 0$ is more convenient.

Comment: @sizz That would raise the question of what negative $r$ actually represents. Mathematically, this is assumed to be in the opposite direction. From the [wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system) page, "Where a unique representation is needed for any point, it is usual to limit r to non-negative numbers (r ≥ 0) and θ to the interval [0, 360°) or (−180°, 180°] (in radians, [0, 2π) or (−π, π]).[12] One must also choose a unique azimuth for the pole, e.g., θ = 0." This is the definition I was using.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Note that,

$$|x|=\sqrt{x^2}\leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}, $$

and the same for $|y|$.